# Passing parameters to SQL queries from a generic ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to create a generic SQL pipeline to query data from a database.

Got a json file for each feed  to pass feed specific parameters to pipeline:

Format of json file  for "emp" feed is as follows

{
"feed_name":"emp",
"query":select * from emp where emp_id=<<emp_id passed from adf pipeline>>,
"raw_base_folder":"raw"
}

Json file for dept is like :
{
"feed_name":"dept",
"query":select * from dept where deptno > <> and deptno< <>,
"raw_base_folder":"raw"
}

Is it possible to create a generic pipeline for all queries executed against a single database but with different parameters passed through ADF pipeline?

I tried to use json files as below:

{
"feed_name":"emp",
"query":"declare @p_emp_id varchar2(100);set @p_emp_id=@{pipeline,parameters().emp_id};select * from emp where emp_id=@p_emp_id"
"raw_base_folder":"raw"
}

and tried to use the above query in a lookup activity /script activity but got the error:

Must declare the scalar variable '@'.

It is throwing error near the statement =@{pipeline,parameters().emp_id};.

Is there any workaround for this issue?..

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is because when you are passing the query from Json file to the script or look up activity it will take whole query as a sting including parameter as below:

[image]

To work around this, you need to use intermediate **set variable** to replace the value of parameter with the pipeline parameter.

```
to replace @{pipeline().parameters.emp_id} with pipline parameter
expression: @replace(activity('Lookup2').output.value[0].query,'@{pipeline().parameters.emp_id}',pipeline().parameters.emp_id)
```

[image]

Now pass this variable in query of script or lookup activity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to wrong syntax:
@{pipeline**,**parameters().emp_id};.

Correct syntax :
@{pipeline**.**parameters().emp_id};.

Also the expression should be a valid sql query .In the query, you have mentioned the expression in json format, kindly use only the sql query inside the json to run in the database